# Unable to run sample CollectD Python plugin code locally

Tags: python, collectd

I am trying to write a python based plugin for CollectD as per their documentation on https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd-python.5.shtml#writing_your_own_plugins

I pip installed collectd locally, and tried to run the hello world plugin as per the documentation page:

```
import collectd
import random

def read(data=None):
  vl = collectd.Values(type='gauge')
  vl.plugin='python.spam'
  vl.dispatch(values=[random.random() * 100])

collectd.register_read(read)
```

However, I am coming across the generic python error when running this code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "CollectdTest1.py", line 9, in 
>   collectd.register_read(read)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'register_read'

Can someone help explain what I am missing here to be able to run the plugin?

This error seems to have nothing to do with CollectD actually running locally or not - just trying to create the 'collectd.Values' object also gives a similar error.

```
import collectd
collectd.Values(type='gauge')
```

> File "CollectdTest3.py", line 3, in 
>      collectd.Values(type='gauge')
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Values'

Btw, I went through the collectd module source code (file:///Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/collectd.py), and it looks like the 'register_read' function in fact is not in the module.

I have tried searching for someone encountering a similar issue on Google and StackOverflow, but to no avail :( .

FYI, I am running Python version 2.7.10 on my MacOS Sierra.

Please note that I am new to both Python as well as CollectD, so this is likely a newbie question.

Comment: Do you have a script named `collectd.py` in the current directory?  If so, that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, John. I do not have a collectd.py in my current directory, however.

Comment: Try this code: `import collectd; print (collectd.__file__)` to make sure that it's importing the correct file.

Comment: Thanks, John. Yeah, that points to the source code that I went through that I mentioned above. 
It seems to me that PIP has possibly installed another module with the same name? I'm not sure how module name conflicts are resolved in Python... 
I'm not sure how to get the correct version of the module either.

Comment: It isn't necessarily an error that `register_read()` is missing from the `collectd.py` module; code for any module can also live inside `__init__.py` in the module directory.

Comment: Okay, it turns out that you cannot actually run CollectD code from Python directly, it needs to be run in the CollectD runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you installed the [`collectd` module from pypi](https://pypi.org/project/collectd/)‚ which is a third-party module that is written to interface with collectd over the network. This module just happens to be named the same as the `collectd` module that collectd itself exposes to its modules.

Collectd implements this by, from within the collectd process, [defining a sort of "virtual" `collectd` python module](https://github.com/collectd/collectd/blob/main/src/python.c#L1251-L1254) and registering some types and methods in this module that can be used by python code *inside* the python interpreter inside the collectd process. In other words, the `collectd` module does not exist as .py files.

This means that you cannot actually use the `collectd` module (at least the one you need) in a standalone process. To test your module, you will have to run it as part of collectd.

To do that, I've defined a minimal collectd config file that only configures the Python plugin, and then run `collectd -f -C my_plugin_debug.conf` to run it in the foreground, or `collectd -T -C my_plugin_debug.conf` to run the read function once and then exit.

For reference, here is the `my_plugin_debug.conf` file I've used to load a `my_plugin.py` from the current directory, plus modules from a virtualenv I'm using, but yours will likely be different:

```
LoadPlugin python

<Plugin python>
  ModulePath "./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/"
  ModulePath "."
  LogTraces true
  Import "my_plugin"
</Plugin>
```